# RewriteRule and passed variables not working

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to make my site more SEO friendly.  I researched this and couple other sites and besically none of the solutions work. The URL rewrite works fine with this simple code:

```
RewriteRule ^testpage\.php$ destination.php [NC,L]
```

However, when I try to implement RewriteRule on pages that are dynamic and passing variable in URL, nothing happens.  This is the code I have right now that does not work:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /prodinfo.php?prodid=$1 [NC,L]
```

I would like to have http://www.mysite.com/products/prodinfo.php?id=268 
converted to http://www.mysite.com/268.html

I am on Apache 2.2 with php.5.3  Thanks.

Comment: What doesn't work? Have you looked at the RewriteLog output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is what you're looking for something like this?

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /products/prodinfo\.php\?id=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1.html? [L,R=301]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+).html$ /products/prodinfo.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyone who accesses: `http://example.com/268.html` in their browser has it converted server-side into: `http://example.com/products/prodinfo.php?id=268` with this:

```
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteRule ^([0-9]+).html/?$ /products/prodinfo.php?id=$1 [NC]
```

... or to do the opposite and translate a visitor's request for: `http://example.com/products/prodinfo.php?id=268` to `http://example.com/268.html` in their browser use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^products/prodinfo.php$ /%1.html? [R]
```

Comment: thanks but it is not exactly what I need.  Your solution REDIRECTS to http:example.com/268.html which ends up being 404 error.  I am trying to get URL rewritten to http:example.com/268.html.  Baiscally, I am trying to do the following http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/